# Update SQL Database from Report (SSRS / Catch Export Event)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reporting-services

In an RDL file, if the user exports to PDF (let's say), I want to mark some rows from the report, in the MSSQL database, as being exported. Can I do that from the RDL itself?

Comment: No, you can not do that. The report export doesn't throw an "event" you could listen to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RDL is purely used for presenting the data. You cannot attach to the Export to PDF button in SSRS and then UPDATE the database.

An alternative would be to use an `ASP.NET` web page with the Report Viewer control with a custom button that exports to PDF and then calls some server side code to `UPDATE` the database with the `marked` rows.

Comment: Bloody hell, he's back full time ;)

Comment: @mattytommo - skillz to pay the billz

Comment: Haha, then use them to pay them, SO doesn't pay the billz :P

Comment: @mattytommo - I get paid per answer. +1 is like +£1

Comment: ZOMG, you must be rich ;)

Comment: I treated the event outside the RDL, but I've +1 for your bills :)